# French text to float .wav French speech software

Tags: audio, speech-synthesis, text, lossless

I need high quality speech so generated to float32 based `.wav` or lossless Flac. I prefer online services but even when looking for an app, I only found English ones.

Not plateform resctricted as it can be any beside Apple products.

Comment: Rather than adding exceptions to your "any platform" claim as people waste their time answering only to be told 'not that one', why don't you actually list the platforms which are acceptable? …& also why you will only consider 32-bit float, which is a rather unusual format to work in, other than for pro audio. [Even some pro audio apps cannot use 32-bit]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 32-bit wav or flac for this, as the voice generated won't be of higher quality than a 128bit mp3/aac.

macOS can read 'text to speech' natively & optionally save to a file in iTunes/Music.

To set this up in a key-commandable form...

- Open TextEdit.
- In the TextEdit menu open TextEdit > Services > Services Preferences…
- Scroll to the section headed Text & open it
- Check "Add to iTunes as Spoken Track" & give it a key command.

[image: screenshot 1]

<sup>image saved from Mojave, newer OSes will look slightly different, but have the same functionality.</sup>

This will then read & save any selected text, system-wide, in whatever language you currently have selected & have the voices enabled for - **System Prefs > Accessibility > Speech > System Voice: > Customise**.

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Disagree with first point as there will be multiple recompressions. Also I don’t have Apple.

Comment: You can convert to wav if you really need to for further processing but the original voice will be low-bitrate, so you gain nothing. If you can't access macOS, then why did you state 'any platform'.. which I see you've now edited out. Really, that just wastes your time & mine.

Comment: …and thank you for the petulant downvote [favour dutifully returned]. Don't shoot the messenger if you can't ask for what you actually need.

Comment: I forgot I don’t own Apple, and then you answered something different. .wav don’t have limit on bitrate.

Comment: I answered the question as asked, with a frame challenge on why you think you need 32-bit wav. Then you moved the goalposts. You still haven't explained why you think you need 32-bit wav. *".wav don’t have limit on bitrate"* kind of shows you don't know what you're asking for or why. Of course it has a bit-rate, it's just the same as the sampling rate.

Comment: `high quality` written in the question ?

Comment: You can't have any higher quality than the voice samples are made at. You clearly have bo clue how this works. I'm done arguing with you.

Comment: `tts`isn’t fully sample.